# how to create routes that accepts any number of path parameters in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have to pass dynamic list of email addresses in the `GET` request, e.g.

```
GET http://example.com/adil@gmail.com/foobar@yahoo.com/.... and so on.
```

I tried to do it with the following code.

```
http://example.com/sendmail/{list}
```

Can this be done with passing `Array` as a `GET` parameter?

Comment: Could you add a more detailed code example, I don't see the GET request.

Comment: How long is that list, and Why can you not use the body of a POST request?

Comment: if you need to pass n number of emails, you can use a comma-separated URL encoded string as a single param `GET http://example.com/adil%40gmail.com%2Cfoobar%40yahoo.com` then explode it from the controller

Comment: Actually I wanted to pass an Array or Associative Array in the URL. I was just practicing, I know, we can pass data via POST securely.